# Navigation View Galaxy S 3 issue

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, navigationview

Navigation View from new Android design library seems to have a issue in Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3). When I start opening de drawer, the background turns completely black, as I show in the image link. Any tip to solve? Thanks!

[Screenshot navigation view galaxy s3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhgCph_U3B1X2tYY3RwemtJS28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: your image link does not show any view.

Comment: image is not working

Comment: Thanks, it should be work now.